# Does this condition for finding the limit points work?

Tags: general-topology

I am reading *Topology Without Tears*, and I've been scribbling notes in the margin trying to streamline some of Morris's more... inefficient explanations. Being the soulless automaton that I am, I always try to state definitions in computation-friendly way. To that end, does this work as a definition for limit points?

> Let $X$ be a set and $T$ a topology on $X$. For $A\subseteq X$, $x$ is
>   a limit point of $A$ iff $\{x\}\notin\bigcup_{\tau\in T} \{A\cap\tau\}$.

As far as I can tell, this directly follows from definition 3.1.1

> Let $A$ be a subset of a topological space $(X,\mathcal{T})$. A point $x\in X$ is said to be a limit point (or accumulation point or cluster point) of $A$ if every open set, $U$, containing $x$ contains a point of $A$ different from $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, your union loses the part of the definition where we only consider open sets that contain $x$. If we denote by $O_x =\{O \in \tau: x \in O\}$, the set of open neighbourhoods of $x$, then $x$ is a limit point of $A$ iff $\emptyset \notin \{O \cap A: O \in O_x\}$ and $\{x\} \notin \{O \cap A: O \in O_x\}$, or equivalently

$$\{\emptyset, \{x\}\} \cap \{O \cap A: O \in O_x\} = \emptyset$$

This way of seeing it might be useful if the topology would be given by a list of sets $O_x$, for each $x \in X$, which is one of the options to "encode" a topology.

Comment: Isn't your second condition included by the union, since $O_x\subseteq\tau$ and $\{O\cap A:O\in O_x\}=\bigcup_{O\in O_x} \{O\cap A\}$? If so, would my original definition be correct if I had included your first condition? Your definition is more efficient, so I'll probably use it anyway, I just wanted to check my reasoning.

Comment: @R.Burton what do you mean by the “second condition included in the union”?

Comment: $\bigcup_{O\in O_x} \{O\cap A\}\subseteq \bigcup_{U\in \tau} \{U\cap A\}$, so if $\{x\}\notin\bigcup_{U\in \tau} \{U\cap A\}$, then $\{x\}\notin \bigcup_{O\in O_x} \{O\cap A\}$.

Comment: @R.Burton true, but I test fewer sets. And the empty set should also be checked. And there you do restrict to open sets containing $x$ or else it’s false.

Comment: If $x$ is a limit point, then there is no $\tau\in T$ for which $A\cap\tau=\{x\}$, and conversely if there is no such $\tau$ then $x$ would have to be a limit point, no?

Comment: @anon no, take $A=(0,1)$ and $x=2$ there is no such $\tau$ but $x$ is not a limit point.

Comment: Ah, duh. ${}{}$

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't work. The right-hand side is simply $A$ itself, so you ended up defining the complement of $A$, not its limit points.

Explanation:

- Since clearly $A\cap\tau\subseteq A$ for any $\tau$, we have that $\bigcup_{\tau\in T}A\cap\tau\subseteq A$.
- Since $\tau=X\in T$ by definition of a topology, we have that $A=A\cap X\subseteq\bigcup_{\tau\in T}A\cap\tau$.

P.S. And a quick note regarding notation: it should be either "$\{x\}\not\subseteq\bigcup_{\tau\in T}A\cap\tau$" or "$x\notin\bigcup_{\tau\in T}A\cap\tau$".

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I made a mistake, it should have been $\{A\cap\tau\}$ instead of $A\cap\tau$, sorry.